# Annotation @XmlElement write only?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cxf, jax-rs

I'm new to java XML binding.

This is my class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * @author Martin Burchard
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
    public class User {
    private String id;
    private String nickname;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "nickname")
    public String getNickName() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    public String getEMail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEMail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

During creation/registration of a user the password must be given, but later, when asking for userinformation, the XML should not contain the password element.
Is it possible to define an Element as writeonly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB 2 (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy has an `@XmlReadOnly` extension.  The field/property annotated with `@XmlReadOnly` will be populated during an unmarshal (read), but will not be written during a marshal.

**User**

```
package forum10208143;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlReadOnly;

/**
 * @author Martin Burchard
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String nickname;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "nickname")
    public String getNickName() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    public String getEMail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEMail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    @XmlReadOnly
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properites**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10208143;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10208143/input.xml");
        User user = (User) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <id>jdoe</id>
    <nickname>Jane</nickname>
    <email>jane.doe@example.com</email>
    <password>secret</password>
</user>
```

**Output**

```
secret
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
   <email>jane.doe@example.com</email>
   <id>jdoe</id>
   <nickname>Jane</nickname>
</user>
```

Comment: I looked on the Webpage of EclipseLink and also in the Maven repository, but had not found the libraries. Can you help me define this package in my Maven dependencies?

Comment: @user1177897 - The following should help:  https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is not such option, I suggest you use a derived class like "ReadOnlyUser" that won't include the password field.

Comment: I also thought in this direction, but had the hope, that this is not necessary. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

- I set up the access type as none, to be able to annotate fields and properties.
- Then annotated the password property with the method returning ****.
- Then another getter that returns the unencrypted password.

Don't know if it's all 'accepted, but so far it works....

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User {
```

...

```
private String password = null;
@XmlElement(required=false, name="password")
public String getPassword() { 
    return (password == null || password.isEmpty()) ? null : "**********"; 
}

@XmlTransient
public String getUnencryptedPassword() { 
    return this.password; 
}
```